# How to load unlabelled data for sentiment classification after training SVM model?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python-3.7, sentiment-analysis, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to do sentiment classification and I used sklearn SVM model. I used the labeled data to train the model and got 89% accuracy. Now I want to use the model to predict the sentiment of unlabeled data. How can I do that? and after classification of unlabeled data, how to see whether it is classified as positive or negative?

I used python 3.7. Below is the code.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("label data for testing .csv", header=0)
sentiment_data = list(zip(data['Articles'], data['Sentiment']))
random.shuffle(sentiment_data)

train_x, train_y = zip(*sentiment_data[:350])
test_x, test_y = zip(*sentiment_data[350:])

from nltk import word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn import metrics


clf = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(analyzer="word",
                                   tokenizer=word_tokenize,
                                   preprocessor=lambda text: text.replace("<br />", " "),
                                   max_features=None)),
    ('classifier', LinearSVC())
])

clf.fit(train_x, train_y)
pred_y = clf.predict(test_x)
print("Accuracy : ", metrics.accuracy_score(test_y, pred_y))
print("Precision : ", metrics.precision_score(test_y, pred_y))
print("Recall : ", metrics.recall_score(test_y, pred_y))
```

When I run this code, I get the output:

> ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations.   "the number of iterations.", ConvergenceWarning)
>   Accuracy :  0.8977272727272727 
>   Precision :  0.8604651162790697 
>   Recall :  0.925

What is the meaning of ConvergenceWarning?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of ConvergenceWarning?

As Pavel already mention, ConvergenceWArning means that the `max_iter`is hitted, you can supress the warning here: [How to disable ConvergenceWarning using sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784971/how-to-disable-convergencewarning-using-sklearn)

> Now I want to use the model to predict the sentiment of unlabeled
>   data. How can I do that?

You will do it with the command: `pred_y = clf.predict(test_x)`, the only thing you will adjust is :`pred_y` (this is your free choice), and `test_x`, this should be your new unseen data, it has to have the same number of features as your data `test_x` and `train_x`.

In your case as you are doing:

```
sentiment_data = list(zip(data['Articles'], data['Sentiment']))
```

You are forming a tuple: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031056/how-to-form-tuple-column-from-two-columns-in-pandas)
then you are shuffling it and [unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139350/difference-between-ziplist-and-ziplist/29139418) the first 350 rows:

```
train_x, train_y = zip(*sentiment_data[:350])
```

Here you `train_x` is the column: `data['Articles']`, so all you have to do if you have new data:

```
new_ data = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv", header=0)
new_y = clf.predict(new_data['Articles'])
```

> how to see whether it is classified as positive or negative?

You can run then: `pred_y`and there will be either a 1 or a 0 in your outcome. Normally 0 should be negativ, but it depends on your dataset-up

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the same number of features. Does that mean the number of the column? As my labeled data has two columns - one for articles, and the other one for the label (sentiment). If I use unlabeled data, then it will only have one column for articles. Can you please write it in code what you mentioned in your second argument?

Comment: Thank you for helping. I did what you mentioned but I am running into the error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [88, 179]. My labeled data have 438 rows and 2 columns. And new_data (unlabeled data) has 179 rows and 1 column.

Comment: She shapes must matching, otherwise it will not work, you have to adjust your data...

Comment: I got the 1, but how do I get a polarity for each piece of text in the unlabelled data?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [site](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) about model's persistence. Then you just load it and call `predict` method. Model will return predicted label. If you used any encoder (`LabelEncoder`, `OneHotEncoder`), you need to dump and load it separately.

If I were you, I'd rather do full data-driven approach and use some pretrained embedder. It'll also work for dozens of languages out-of-the-box with is quite neat.

There's [LASER](https://engineering.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/) from facebook. There's also [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/laserembeddings/) package, though unofficial. It works just fine.
Nowadays there's a lot of pretrained models, so it shouldn't be that hard to reach near-seminal scores.

Answer (score -1):

> Now I want to use the model to predict the sentiment of unlabeled data. How can I do that? and after classification of unlabeled data, how to see whether it is classified as positive or negative?

Basically, you aggregate unlabeled data in same way as `train_x` or `test_x` is generated. Probably, it's 2D matrix of shape `n_samples x 1`, which you would then use in `clf.predict` to obtain predictions. `clf.predict` outputs most probable class. In your case `0` is negative and `1` is positive, but it's hard to tell without the dataset.

> What is the meaning of ConvergenceWarning?

LinearSVC model is optimized using iterative algorithm. There is an argument `max_iter` (1000 by default) that controls maximum amount of iterations. If stopping criteria wasn't met during this process, you will get `ConvergenceWarning`. It shouldn't bother you much, as long as you have acceptable performance in terms of accuracy, or other metrics.