# What is the time/space complexity of zip(*a[::-1])?

Tags: python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

If `a` is a `List[List[int]]` representing a n✕n matrix, what is the time- and space-complexity of `a = zip(*a[::-1])`?

### My thoughts

- Time-complexity has to be at least O(n^2) because we touch n^2 elements. I guess that every element is touched exactly twice (reversing/flipping with `a[::-1]` and transposing with `zip(*reversed)`)
- `list(zip(*a[::-1]))` returns a copy, so the space-complexity would be at least n^2. But zip returns an iterator, hence I'm not sure.
- I'm especially uncertain about the space complexity, because I read that `zip(*inner)` unpacks the inner iterables ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139418/562769)). My guess is that it stores additionally to the input O(n) for keeping pointers for the n inner "unpacked" iterators. But I'm very uncertain about that.